# Informatica - Is it possible to set a workflow variable in a command task without using a script?

Tags: sh, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a file (X) which contains a single line specifying the location and name of another file (Y). X is captured within a workflow variable but Y isn't, and I need to pass Y as a parameter to a post SQL command in one of the sessions. Since this should be possible using a single line with `basename $(head -n 1 $$X)`, I am hesitant to create a script specifically for this (also since there are no other scripts currently used).

Is there a way to assign the output of a command (the one specified above) to a workflow variable?

Comment: can you do `$(head -n 1 $$X)` and store it in a temp param file. And then use this file in post session command to kick off another workflow?

Comment: @KoushikRoy - I'm not sure I understand what you meant. Wouldn't ````$(head -n 1 $$X)```` just be the content of X already? Using it in a post session command still implies I need some script to parse out the filename.

Comment: The mapping that youre talking about generates X file - right? If yes, then, session will generate it and post session will use to create file Y. and another post session is needed to kick off the other workflow